# Recieving "No results found" message when attempting to access chrome content provider via adb shell

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

Im trying to access the browsing history of my mobile browser (Chrome) via adb shell.The command i'm using is:
content query --uri content://com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.provider.ChromeBrowserProvider

Please correct me if i'm wrong, but the string "com.android.chrome" is the name of Content Provider of the Chrome app, and the string "org.chromium.chrome.browser.provider.ChromeBrowserProvider" is a reference to the database table that i'm presuming contains data related to my browsing history.

When i run this command i get a "No results found" message in the shell terminal so obviously there's something i'm missing here.Am i going about this the right way? Is my content uri structured correctly? Can anyone provide me some sort of link that can help me out with accessing data specifically from the Chrome content provider via adb shell?  If it makes any difference i'm using powershell on windows 10 and my phone is android 10